# Is it possible to speed up Cassandra cleanup process?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have Cassandra 3.11.1.0 cluster (6 nodes) and cleanup was not done after 2 nodes were joined.

I started `nodetool cleanup` on first node (192.168.20.197) and cleanup is in progress almost 30 days.

```
$ nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.20.109  33.47 GiB  256          ?       677dc8b6-eb00-4414-8d15-9f1c79171069  rack1
UN  192.168.20.47   35.41 GiB  256          ?       df8c1ee0-fabd-404e-8c55-42531b89d462  rack1
UN  192.168.20.98   20.65 GiB  256          ?       70ce02d7-779b-4b5a-830f-add6ed64bcc2  rack1
UN  192.168.20.21   33.03 GiB  256          ?       40863a80-5f25-464f-aa52-660149bc0070  rack1
UN  192.168.20.197  25.98 GiB  256          ?       5420eae3-e643-49e2-b2d8-703bd5a1f2d4  rack1
UN  192.168.20.151  21.9 GiB   256          ?       be7d5df1-3edd-4bc3-8f34-867cb3b8bfca  rack1
```

All nodes which were not cleaned are under load now, (CPU Load ~80-90% ) but new-joined (nodes 192.168.20.98  and  192.168.20.151 ) nodes have CPU Load ~10-20%

It looks like old nodes are loaded because of old data which can be cleaned up.

Each node has 61GB RAM and 8 CPU Cores. HEAP size is 30Gb

So, my questions are

- Is it possible to speed up cleaning process?
- Is CPU Load related to the old unused (which node is not owns
  anymore) data on nodes?